# Java using of finalize() in context of OpenGL

Tags: java, opengl, garbage-collection

I am writing a little OpenGL graphics "engine". As I learned so far one should avoid the use of the `finalize` in Java, because it is slowing down the GC.

I am doing the release of the OpenGL ressources by myself, by registering all ressources (`Texture`, `Shader` (all implement `Destroyable`)) I use in a class called `OpenGL`. This class has the public static methods `render`, `init` and `destroy`.
So if someone uses this engine he has to call the `destroy` method of `OpenGL`.

Would it be an appropriated use-case to use the `finalize()` method to destroy the object if any dumb programmer forgets to call `OpenGL.destroy()`?

That would be my `finalize()` method:

```
@Override
protected void finalize() {
    if(!isDestroyed())
        try {
            destroy();
        } catch (DestroyFailedException e) {}
}
```

Comment: nothing wrong with that except that the finalizers may never run at all

Comment: I know that, thats why the user/programmer should call `OpenGL.destroy()`. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context it seems to be a good solution to use the `finalize()` method to throw an Exception to the user to draw attention to the fault of not destroying the object.

Answer (score 1):

Destroying the objects in `finalize()` is not a good idea, even if it is conditional.

Beyond the general concerns with `finalize()`, the problem is that you can only make the calls to destroy the OpenGL objects from a thread that has a current OpenGL context, which must be either your rendering thread, or another thread that has an OpenGL context in the same share group. As far as I know, GC will normally run in its own thread(s), so you can't count on having a current OpenGL context in the `finalize()` method.

Adding diagnostics to the `finalize()` method to detect when a programmer missed to call the `destroy()` method, as suggested in the answer by @FlushFish, sounds like a good idea. But that's about as much as you should do.